# rails 4 bundle install guard error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

Recently I started getting this warning when running `bundle install` and I am curious if I should be alarmed or how I can fix this? So far google has not been any help.

> guard at
>   /SocialPlatform/.bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/guard-19351271941a
>   did not have a valid gemspec. This prevents bundler from installing
>   bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
>   The validation message from Rubygems was:   ["man/guard.2"] are not
>   files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a warning.  If this is your application and you don't understand it, then perhaps you don't need it.

If you were creating a gem, and it doesn't make sense, it will as you start to research the gemspec, and what it is used for.

The file.gemspec file is used by other gems to help resolve dependencies, and so as stated, may or may not effect your applications functionality.  And of course it is used by bundler as stated.

To "fix" it, create a gemspec that is valid.